# What is the difference between 依偎 and 偎傍？

Tags: difference

I looked them up and they both have relatively the same meaning. So what's the difference between the two?

Comment: Though word differentiation questions are fine to ask, it is preferred to provide more context so the answers can be more directed to the actual problem.

Answer (score 3):

依偎 implies a strong sentimental attachement, usually expressing love or affection. Mostly used between couples, lovers, child and parent.

偎傍 doesn't necessarily carry so much personal feelings, just meaning "stay side by side closely" and is seldom to use in informal/oral conversation. I think it's original from Chinese poems.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a understanding:

```
依偎->weak 依偎 strong
偎傍->have same strength
```

for example, 依偎 is used as a baby(weak in strength) 依偎 his mother (stronger in strength), and 偎傍 is used as two comrade(have the same strength) 偎傍 each other. There is more example, '杨柳依偎磐石'，'磐石相互偎傍'.

Comment: Can you please improve your answer to explain clearly what you are trying to say. Low quality answers that don't provide a full answer may be removed.

Comment: Who can give more example!?